# I forgot how to capture a post in php

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to capture the `$_POST` from this form:

```
        <?php
            var_dump($_POST);
        ?>
        <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Name*">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <input type="email" class="form-control input-lg" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Email*">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Position">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Company">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <textarea class="form-control input-lg" rows="3" cols="10" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-6 col-sm-6">
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-custom-sbmit" value="Send" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
```

and some how I keep failing because when I enter the details, and hit submit I get and array back: `array(0) { }`.

This is probably one of the most basic things, yet I forgot ow to do it. **Ideas?**

Comment: `@Kyle Adams` you need to mark any answer as desired answer, if it is helpful and resolved your problem.thanks.you can vote up others if they are helpful also.

Comment: If an answer solved your problem, consider accepting the answer. Here's how http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234… then return here and do the same with the tick/check mark till it turns green. This informs the community, a solution was found. Otherwise, others may think the question is still open and may want to post (more) answers. You'll earn points and others will be encouraged to help you. Welcome to Stack!

Answer (score 4):

You have no `name` attributes for your `<input>` form elements. As a result nothing is sent to the server. You can verify this by using Firebug or Chrome's developer tools to see no data is sent.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Name*">
```

should be

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="inputEmail3" placeholder="Name*">
```

etc.